# Issues with labels for Turbo C and inline x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, turbo-c++

I am trying to migrate some of my 16-bit Real Mode OS projects to work with Turbo C Compiler 3.1

I have the following issue when trying to use labels within my inline assembly:

```
void mos_io_print_string_c(char* str, char color) {
asm {
    MOV     SI, [str]       // point SI to str
    MOV     BL, [color]     // point BL to color
    MOV     AH, 03h         // get current location of cursor
    INT     10h             // call BIOS
_do:    
    LODSB                   // load the next char from our string
    CMP     AL, 0           // at the end of our string?
    JE      _done           // if so, leave
    MOV     AH, 02h         // set cursor pos: whatever is set
    INT     10h             // call BIOS
    INC     DL              // increase cursor horiz pos
    MOV     AH, 09h         // output char with attributes
    MOV     BH, 0           // set page to write to
    MOV     CX, 1           // number of times to print character
    INT     10h             // call BIOS
    JMP     _do             // loop
_done:  
    MOV     AH, 0Eh         // setup AH for BIOS output char
    MOV     AL, 0Dh         // carriage return
    INT     10h             // output carriage return
    MOV     AL, 0Ah         // new line
    INT     10h             // output new line
}}
```

I am getting the following output from Turbo C vs. 3.1:

```
Compiling PS.C:
.Error PS.C 39: Undefined label '_do'
 Error PS.C 39: Undefined label '_done'
```

I have tried everything including adding `@@` symbols to the labels.  I have even tried to reference them using `CS:_do` and `CS:_done`.  I have also tried using the `NEAR` operator with the labels.  I know that Turbo C is old, but I am limited in my choice of 16-bit C compilers.  If anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's been a few years but I believe you need to break up the inline assembly blocks and define regular C labels, which the branch instructions can then jump to (without any name decoration)

edit: Google turned up an old user's guide with the details - http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~celio/mc404/turboc201/embedded-asm.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by regular "C Labels"?

Comment: The kind you jump to with goto. The syntax is the same but you need to split your asm { } blocks around them with the labels in the middle. E.g. void foo() { my_loop: asm { jmp my_loop } }

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, labels inside an inline block must actually be located out of inline blocks. That is:

```
asm 
{
  instruction
  instruction
}
label:
asm
{
  instruction
  instruction
  jnz label
}
```